# Error when loading custom font in Community - 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community, css, static-resources, font

I've set up the fonts to load exactly as specified in https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.communities_dev.meta/communities_dev/communities_dev_customize_font.htm and they work most of the time, just some times the page will load without the fonts and the following error is displayed in the console log.

`GET https://cchubdev-charteredaccountantsanz.cs72.force.com/sfsites/c/resource/CAANZ_Public_FontImg/fonts/NexaBold.woff 500 (Internal Server Error)`

You can replicate the error by going here https://cchubdev-charteredaccountantsanz.cs72.force.com/CustomerHub/s/login/SelfRegister and hitting "Empty Cache and Hard Reload" a couple of times.

It seems to appear as a `503 (Service Unavailable)` error for users who are not logged in to the community.

Custom CSS

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'NexaBold';
    src: url("/sfsites/c/resource/CAANZ_Public_FontImg/fonts/NexaBold.woff") format('woff');
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Cheers,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

try to use:

`/resource/CAANZ_Public_FontImg/fonts/NexaBold.woff`

instead of:

`/sfsites/c/resource/CAANZ_Public_FontImg/fonts/NexaBold.woff`